# Why does my pointer still point to an address after deleting it?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am learning C++ and I have trouble understanding certain behavior related to pointer.

I have an easy custom object looking like this:

```
class Human {
public:
       //constructor here
private:
       std::string name;
       std::string address;
}
```

another custom object that has an instance variable type of a pointer to human:

```
class property {
public:
       Human * ppl;//pointer to the above human object
}
```

and running this piece of code:

```
Human * human = new Human("Mark", "address");// pointer address 0x123456 for example
Property * property = new Property();
property->ppl = human;//pass the pointer to property's instance variable 
delete human; 
human = NULL;//after deleting and setting it to NULL property.ppl still points to 0x123456
```

After running the above code, the ppl instance variable under property still points to the original memory address but the content of it(name and address) are all cleared(empty string now), I am wondering why is this the behavior? Since I passed the raw pointer around, why after deleting it and setting it to NULL, it still points to a memory address but the content of it has been cleared?

FYI: I am using XCode as the debugging IDE and C++11

Comment: Because you set `human` to null, not `property.ppl`. These are two separate unrelated varaibles. Setting one does not automatically change the other.

Comment: Because c++ is a language without garbage collector. If a reference to something is somewhere in the memory it's up to you to set it to NULL in all the place or just one of them or do not set it to NULL anywhere.

Comment: Pointers only go one way. There is no back channel to tell pointers that what they pointed to no longer exists.

Comment: Pointers are hard to manage. This is a left over from another language (`C`). You should preferably not be using them (pointers) at all in C++. You should be using automatic objects most of the time or higher level constructs (like `std::unique_ptr`) which have the semantics you want when you **must** have dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 5):

Look at this simpler example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;
b = 45;
```

Setting the value of `b` does **not** change the value of `a`. In the same way, setting the value of `human` in your code does not change the value of `property->ppl`.

This concept has nothing to do with `delete`. However, in the case of a pointer, you have to be very careful because `property.ppl` no longer points to valid memory. You can access it, but will likely cause a segmentation fault or some other error that is very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does my pointer still point to an address after deleting it?

You are mistaken. The pointer has an invalid value. It does not point to the object it used to point, nor to any other object.

> I am wondering why is this the behavior?

The behaviour is the way it is because that's how the language is specified. When an object is destroyed and its memory deallocated, all pointers (and references) that used to point to that object become invalid.

> why after deleting it and setting it to NULL, it still points ...

You set `human` to null. You never set `property->ppl` to null. Those are separate objects (even though they have the same value - i.e. they point to the same object) and modifying one doesn't affect the other. An anologous situation:

```
int a = 1;
int b = a;
a = 2; // this does not modify b
```

Comment: I don't think the value is unspecified. It's just an invalid pointer.

Comment: @cigien well technically observing the value of an invalid pointer is implementation defined behaviour. I don't see much difference.

Comment: That's true. I think the answer could be edited to make that a little clearer.

Comment: @cigien I re-wrote to concentrate on the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

The two objects one of the type Human and other of the type Property

```
Human * human = new Human("Mark", "address");
Property * property = new Property();
```

occupy different extents of memory allocated for these objects.

In this statement

```
human = NULL;
```

there is being changed the memory extent occupied by the object `human`.

The memory occupied by the object `property` was not changed.

If the class Property would be defined the following way

```
class Property {
public:
       Human * &ppl;//pointer to the above human object
};
```

and an object of the class Property would be created like

```
Property * property = new Property { human };
```

then indeed setting the object `human` to `NULL` or `nullptr` influence on the data member `ppl` because it has a referenced type.